# How important is sprint test plan in agile?

Tags: testing, scrum, software, qa

I have been preparing a test plan for every sprint even if I have a master test plan just to plan the test for the current sprint. I am including topics like:

1. Introduction
2. Purpose
3. Feature Overview
4. Inscope
5. Outscope
6. Assumptions and Risks
7. Approach
8. Test Deliverables
9. Testing Task and Proposed Schedule

Recently after discussing with some of my fellow mates and colleagues. They suggested not to make a sprint test plan and is covered by the master test plan. Is it ok to not make a Sprint Test Plan and go on with the master test plan?

Comment: This depends 100% on your environment. Your colleagues reactions imply not to make one. But there are other factors involved, e.g. your current level of quality and the degree of satisfaction wiht that quality, certifications, investors, upper management, .... Also, only because the team doesn't want a test plan doesn't they don't need one / don't benefit from one. Maybe their problem is not the test plan but their involvement with it.

Comment: What is your role? Are you part of the team? Would it be correct to say you use Scrum, guessing from the terms you use? Or is it really "just agile"?

Comment: @nvoigt - good point, I've assumed scrum as he's talking about Sprints

Comment: "*How important is sprint test plan in agile?*". It's really important … that you *do not* have one! Such waterfall-centric documentation runs completely counter to the whole idea of an agile approach. @Liath offers the perfect answer to your question: the sprint goals and your team's "definition of done" already provides your test plan.

Comment: Thank you @DavidArno - much appreciated

Comment: @nvoigt I am a quality assurance engineer and our team uses scrum.

Comment: If your team uses scrum, then you would be well advised to effectively retrain yourself as [an agile tester](https://www.testingexcellence.com/what-makes-good-agile-tester/) as you'd then find your testing approach fits better with scrum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The biggest problem I see with this is that you're looking at a mini-waterfall rather than a sprint. The description you're giving above forces the team to deliver all or nothing. What if they have 12 items in the sprint and deliver 9? Does that mean you won't test or release what has been done? If so then I dread your release schedule, every time any team member misses any work item you'll fail to deploy - that weekly deploy will quickly become months long.

My suggestion would be that all the information you've put above should already be available.

- Introduction - Sprint Name, Dates, and goal - job done!
- Purpose - See above
- Feature Overview - a list of stories in the sprint
- Inscope - As above
- Outscope - The backlog minus what's above
- Assumptions and Risks - this depends on what your company is expecting but there's no reason you can't capture risks to stories during backlog refinement. Again, the key is that it's a risk to the story not a risk to the release. Product/Team risk management should be handled outside the sprint framework.
- Approach - Part of the stories themselves
- Test Deliverables - Can you deliver a story without testing it?
- Testing Task and Proposed Schedule - as above

The point I'm trying to make is that all of this information should be available to anyone who wants it either through a link to the Sprint or a link to the story.

My biggest piece of advice - testing is not a phase, it's one of the tasks required to complete a story. Identify the tests you'll do on each story at the same time as identifying the development tasks.

Answer (score 2):

It's very tempting to answer your question with "it depends", since that's the answer to many *"should I...?"* questions.

In this case, however, the answer is **no**. You should not create a sprint test plan. At least, not a formal one. The only test plan you need for a sprint is "verify that every completed story is well tested".

As a QA engineer on a scrum team, part of your responsibility should be to work with the product owner and the developers to identify appropriate acceptance criteria before the sprint starts. Thus, by the time the sprint starts you should already have a plan, which is represented by the acceptance criteria for each story.